# Clicking on Job Links results in "Something Bad Happened"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I click on a job ad on the front page I get "Something Bad Happened":

[image]

The text of the link is:

> `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Fso-proxy%2Fjobs%2F83838%2Fjavascript-developer-needed-for-software-pietech-inc-moneyguidepro%3Fclcid%3D170095%26med%3Dclc%26ref%3Dsmall-sidebar-blue-looking`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed. We made some changes to mobile views that ended up leaking to all views inadvertently. Should be all good now <3